# Prevent ASP.NET Core MVC Form Tag Helper from Encoding Array in GET Querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

Is it possible to instruct the Form Tag Helpers to not URL encode a route parameter?

Specifically, I am using index notation to pass a complex type in the querystring. This worked very nicely in an API project; the controller parsed it perfectly into the C# object (see below).

In the website project today, the controller parses it from the querystring without error, but if I try to feed it into the tag helpers of a form (so that the form keeps that object in the URL on subsequent GETs), the string is URL encoded. This looks bad and the controller doesn't parse it back.

I am using ASP.NET Core 1.1

Thanks in advance. I dug around for this one but couldn't find a work-around; I'm sure I just missed it.

**FORM:**

```
<form method="get"
asp-controller="Search"
asp-action="Index"
asp-route-object_id="@Model.Object.ID"
asp-route-s="@Model.serviceRequests">
```

**Object:**

```
public class ServiceRequest
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int seq { get; set; }
    public List<int> addOns { get; set; }
    public string employee { get; set; }
}
```

**Object as it appears in action method definition:**

```
[FromQuery] List<ServiceRequest> s
```

**Example of a GET request that works:**

```
/controller/action?s[0].id=358&s[1].id=9788&s[1].addOns[0]=93277
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do a `@XYZ` you're telling Razor to encode `XYZ`. To work around this you can do `@Html.Raw(XYZ)`.